# Apply jquery in link inside an iframe

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following working code that just applies some styles in a iframed textarea:

```
`$("#ctl00_m_g_f2a05a6e_efee_4fc1_9c2f_7bb3efaa99a9_ctl00_txtDescricao_iframe").contents().find("body").attr("style","font-size: 11pt !important; font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Segoe UI Web', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif !important; background-color: #FFFFFF !important; border: 0px !important;")`
```

And I have the following non-working code that should add an image when it finds a link:

```
$('#ctl00_m_g_f2a05a6e_efee_4fc1_9c2f_7bb3efaa99a9_ctl00_txtDescricao_iframe a').append('<img id="LinkImage" src="http://server/Link.png" />')
```

Trying to put both code together but without lucky.

**Update:**

```
var $frameContents = $("#ctl00_m_g_f2a05a6e_efee_4fc1_9c2f_7bb3efaa99a9_ctl00_txtDescricao_iframe").contents();
//works
$frameContents.find("body").attr("style","font-size: 11pt !important; font-family: 'Segoe UI', 'Segoe UI Web', 'Segoe UI Symbol', 'Helvetica Neue', Arial, sans-serif !important; background-color: #FFFFFF !important; border: 0px !important;");
//dont work
$frameContents.find("a").append("<img id='LinkImage' src='http://server/Link.png' />");
//dont work
$frameContents.find("img").attr("style","border: 1px #EDEDED solid; padding: 8px; margin-top: 5px; margin-bottom: 20px;");
```

Generated code:
[image]

Comment: Should you have id of 'a' tag in which you want to append img?

Answer (score 1):

Your first example is searching within `contents()` for the elements but second example is using a descendant selector which won't work.

You need to use `$(iframeSelector).contents().find('a')` to make a collection of all `<a>` inside the iframe

To combine both just store reference to the contents

```
var $frameContents = $("#ctl00_m_g_f2a05a6e_efee_4fc1_9c2f_7bb3efaa99a9_ctl00_txtDescription_iframe").contents();

$frameContents.find('body').attr('style', '....');
$frameContents.find('a').append('.....');
// OR
$frameContents.find('body').attr('style', '....').find('a').append('.....');
```

Comment: Couldn't get this to work, but thanks, the way you draw is the way I need to get it.

Comment: Are you waiting for iframe to load? Is there any javscript loading some of the content?

Comment: The iframe is loaded already. I just updated the question with situation. Thanks.

Comment: Well now you completely changed question using my code which invalidates my answer. Not clear what isn't working. Check `$frameContents.find('a').length` to see if you are finding any

Answer (score 0):

If you have id of 'a' tag then please try with following script.

```
var $a = $("#ctl00_m_g_f2a05a6e_efee_4fc1_9c2f_7bb3efaa99a9_ctl00_txtDescription_iframe").contents().find("a#id_of_a");                
$a.append('<img id="LinkImage" src="http://site.server.com/Link.png" />');
```

Comment: I don't have an id for 'a'.

Comment: Do you have unique class for that 'a' or href value of that 'a' in which you want to append img?